# JSON view in Recess Framework

Tags: php, json, api, recess

I am trying to create an api with Recess and I have a question about its JsonView. Currently, if I do a GET request on, for example, /users/1 (which routes to a function that gets all the details for the user with id 1 and responds with Json), I get the following:

```
{"users":{"id":"1","username":null,"password":null,"datejoined":false}}
```

How can I make it so that I get the following instead:

```
{"id":"1","username":null,"password":null,"datejoined":false}
```

That is, I don't want all the details wrapped inside `"users":{}`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default, Recess's JsonView [responds](https://github.com/recess/recess/blob/47444bc8b6dc367460220be47f08f20c0392e7e5/recess/recess/framework/views/JsonView.class.php#L25) with the [properties of your controller](https://github.com/recess/recess/blob/47444bc8b6dc367460220be47f08f20c0392e7e5/recess/recess/framework/controllers/Controller.class.php#L208). So your `$users` property is getting directly encoded into JSON.

You can override this by returning a [custom response object](https://github.com/recess/recess/blob/47444bc8b6dc367460220be47f08f20c0392e7e5/recess/recess/http/responses/OkResponse.class.php):

```php
return new OkResponse($this->request, (array)$this->users);
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure about recess specifically, but if you are using JsonView method/function with an input parameter `(array) $result`, then changing `$result` to `$result['users']` may give you the answer you are looking for.

For example using plain PHP:

```
first object: echo json_encode($result);
second object: echo json_encode($result['users']);
```

Comment: Yes that's what I'm after. However, I'm hoping to use the JsonView for all the controllers and $result['users'] will only work for the users controller. Do you know how to make it work for all controllers in Recess?